# local image not loading in <Image> react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

First I tried to load image with following code  and it does load the image

```
render(){
return(
  <View style={{backgroundColor:'red', flex:1, alignItems:'center'}}>
    <Text> Landing Page controller</Text>
    <Image
    source={require('./symbol.png')}
  />
  </View>
);  }
```

[image]
Now i have load lots of image through out the application from different files. In such case it is very difficult to maintain the code and resources. That's why I created the separate file

**resource.js**

```
 module.export= {
                symbol:require('./symbol.png'),
              };
```

and then in component file I  tried to load like below.

```
import JResource from './resource.js';
   .....................
   ..................
 render(){
        return(
          <View style={{backgroundColor:'red', flex:1, alignItems:'center'}}>
            <Text> Landing Page controller</Text>
            <Image
            source={JResource.symbol}
          />
          </View>
        );
      }
```

Now the application did run , but no image is displayed. It would be great if any body would figure out  what's wrong here.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should module.exports = ..... not export